# Ordering a csv file by ascending value when the file is imported via numpy.loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy, csv, scipy

I am importing a csv file where each header has a string with a number inside the string. See the image; downloading the spreadsheet is not required, it's just a visual aid.
[image: Data set]
As you can see, for each observation there is a number in the string, e.g. "Observation: 19909". I want to re-order this data by ascending observation number. The wavelength column should remain in its placed, but next to that should be the column of data with "Observation: #lowest number#" and at the rightmost column at the end of the data should have "Observation: #highest number#".

I have imported the data with this python code:

```
spectral_data=np.loadtxt(r'C:/Users/Sidharth/Documents/Computing Labs/Project 1/Halpha_spectral_data.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=2) #importing data file
```

**And now I want to order the observation columns in spectral_data by ascending observation number. How can I do this?**. It goes without saying that I cannot edit the spreadsheet in excel itself.

Edit: I have some code which can print simply the integer from the Observation number string, but I'm not sure if/how I can incorporate this into achieving the task in the question. Here is that code:

```
with open('C:/Users/Sidharth/Documents/Computing Labs/Project 1/Halpha_spectral_data.csv','r') as file:
    line1=file.readline()
    line2=file.readline()
    line1_split=line1.split(',')
    line2_split=line2.split(',')
    str1=('White Space')
    str2=str1.strip()
    
print(line2_split)
observation=line2_split
observation=observation[1:]
print(observation)
observation_int = [int(item.split(' ')[1]) for item in observation]
print(observation_int)
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this,
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, a tool which allows to perform your task in a more intuitive
and simpler way is *Pandas*. Furthermore, it allows you to keep column names.

Assume that the input file contains:

```
# Date: 19.10.2020
# Waveler xxx,Observation: 19909,Observation: 19908,Observation: 19912
6.60E-07,1.24E+02,1.48E+02,1.33E+02
6.62E-07,1.28E+02,1.35E+02,1.49E+02
```

You can read it into a DataFrame, calling:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', skiprows=1, index_col=0)
```

Note 2 important details:

- `skiprows=1` causes the initial row to be skipped (so column names
  are read from the **second** row and data from following rows,
- `index_col=0` causes that the letfmost column will be the **index**
  of the created DataFrame (not a regular column). The reason is to
  omit this column in sorting of columns.

For the time being, *df* contains:

```
               Observation: 19909  Observation: 19908  Observation: 19912
# Waveler xxx                                                            
6.600000e-07                124.0               148.0               133.0
6.620000e-07                128.0               135.0               149.0
```

so the first 2 columns are in a wrong order.

To sort columns and then change the index into a regular column,
you can run:

```
df = df[df.columns.sort_values()].reset_index()
```

Now *df* contains:

```
   # Waveler xxx  Observation: 19908  Observation: 19909  Observation: 19912
0   6.600000e-07               148.0               124.0               133.0
1   6.620000e-07               135.0               128.0               149.0
```

​If you want a *Numpy* array anyway, not a DataFrame, you can run:

```
arr = df.values
```

but be warned that now you loose column names (in your case observation names).

Comment: This was a great solution. For my use, a numpy array at the end was more useful, so I appreciate your input with that regard too. Thank you so much.